# How to understand OpenJDK versions and find the newest Java 8 image?

Tags: java

I am using [8u151-jdk-alpine3.7](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=tags&page=1&name=8u151-jdk-alpine3.7) in my docker file. I wanted update to newest Java 8 version. 
There are two versions in the image name

- `8u151` which si version of Java
- `alpine3.7` which I can't find definition anywhere

Additionaly there is no clear list of released versions so I could find which version follows [8u151-jdk-alpine3.7](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=tags&page=1&name=8u151-jdk-alpine3.7).

**Question:** Would I search newer version of Java for the same Alpine version(3.7) or newer one? What is the diffrence? It's confusing at least.

Comment: Alpine is just the name of the underlying Docker image name, has nothing to do with the jdk version. It is a very barebone Linux with very few tools pre-installed.

Comment: @daniu Thanks, where is actually official page of OpenJDK where I can see till when OpenJDK Java 8 is long term supported? There are so many pages and none look authentic.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that Java 8u151 for use on [Alpine 3.7](https://alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-3.7.0-released.html)?
If you're not changing the Alpine image then presumably you should be looking for something with a larger number than 8u151, with the rest of the name the same.